# JAVA - Hibernate - Spring-JPA - @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION) not throwing errors

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi to the JAVA community.
Here's the details :

### softs version

- hibernate : 5.6.14.Final
- spring : 5.3.25
- spring-jpa : 2.7.7
- java : Amazon 11 corretto
- Sybase : ASE 12.5.4

### db

Sybase ASE 12.5.4

**PAY**

| Column name | Nullable | Data type | Data type Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PAY_IDT | Unchecked | char | 3 |
| PAY_NOM | Unchecked | varchar | 30 |

With those records :

- 'BEL', 'BELGIUM'
- 'AND', 'ANDORRE'

**PERSON**

| Column name | Nullable | Data type | Data type Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PERSON_IDT | Unchecked | int | 4 |
| PERSON_NOM | Unchecked | varchar | 35 |
| PERSON_PRN | Unchecked | varchar | 25 |
| PERSON_PAY | Unchecked | char | 3 |

with this record :

- 1, 'Doe', 'john', 'AAA'

Relationship between PAY <-> PERSON_PAY
**-->  no Foreign Key defined !!!**

### entities

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "PAY")
@Immutable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Pays implements DictionnaireEntity {

    private String id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PAY_IDT", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String nom;
    @Column(name = "PAY_NOM")
    @Basic
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(final String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Immutable
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {

    private Integer id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_IDT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String nom;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_NOM")
    @Basic
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(final String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    private String prenom;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_PRN")
    @Basic
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }
    public void setPrenom(final String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    private Pays pays;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Pays.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_PAY", nullable = false, foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(value = Constra
    public Pays getPays() {
        return pays;
    }
    public void setPays(final Pays pays) {
        this.pays = pays;
    }
}
```

### repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

### service

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PersonOperationsImpl implements PersonOperations {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public Person get(final int id) throws ApplicationException {
        final Person person = personRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

        if (person == null) {
            throw ExceptionHelper.personNotFound(id);
        }

        return de;
    }
}
```

When I call my service PersonOperationsImpl.get(1), I would expect to receive
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException or hibernate FetchNotFoundException.

What I get is my business exception :
ExceptionHelper.personNotFound(1) --> "PERSON 1 not found" which is not correct.
PERSON 1 is here but there is a broken foreign key reference.

I only receive the javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException on nested entities and collections.
But not here. Why is this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are facing a bug, the root cause is `nullable = false` and or `optional = false` definition: since you defined column as `nullable = false` and/or `optional = false`, HBN "expects" that column `PERSON_PAY` may not store nulls and thus using `left outer join` [does not make sense](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/49fbe84dde773de84ea704bb10193c4c581d34b8/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/plan/build/internal/spaces/QuerySpaceHelper.java#L58) (though, according to the javadoc if `org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode#JOIN` is specified it should you outer join, moreover, IMO, `@NotFound` should influence on resulting SQL as well):

```java
// here `required` defines what join type `inner` or `outer`
// will be used for eager fetch
final boolean required = lhsQuerySpace.canJoinsBeRequired() && !isMultiTable && !attribute.isNullable();

return makeEntityQuerySpace(
    lhsQuerySpace,
    fetchedPersister,
    attribute.getName(),
    (EntityType) attribute.getType(),
    querySpaceUid,
    required,
    shouldIncludeJoin( fetchStrategy )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Interesting, since I had to remove nullable = false for it to work on nested class. But in these case, I already try to remove nullable = false and it doesn't work. Maybe I would have to be more clear in a first place. I've try all combination here with and without nullable = false. I've try to add optional = false on the @ManyToOne relation as well without success.

Comment: I have try FetchMode.Select as well to generate another sql query despite of the n+1 bug and it doesn't work.

Comment: @jocko, Hm... `optional = false` also affects resulting query